# Merge rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql

Bellow I have given my data and I need a way to merge to rows.

```
User id.          Details

1.                Anbcds
1.                Csdf
```

Required outcome

```
1.Anbcdscsdf
```

Comment: Please construct an actual table so it will be more clear

Comment: Thank you.. sachith.

Can you please show me how to use this code in Toad for Oracle..

Answer (score 0):

Use [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190349.aspx) and you need to declare a variable that will hold your output result and select into it,

```
DECLARE @char VARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @char = COALESCE(@char + [Details], [Details]) 
FROM [tblYourTable];

PRINT @char;
```

PS: I tested with SQL Server. Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions023.htm) for Oracle